# Visual Studio Code .NET Core project shows verbose debug console messages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am new to Visual Studio Code. However, one thing thing that I noticed with one of the projects that I have is really bugging me. Whenever, I run the project in Visual Studio Code using its in-built debugger, it shows me a message which looks like following:

> Loaded /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.0/System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enable

And it shows that message for each DLL file that I have referenced. This causes huge amount of unwarranted logs in my *Debug Console*.

- Why does it show this information?
- Is it possible to get rid of it?

Answer (score 16):

**Applies to dotnet core 2.2, reverified with .NET 7 [Core]; unverified anywhere else**

I just found a way to get rid of most of this noise using the `logging` options. Unfortunately, I still see some program output like thread info because we currently have logging going to the console. I haven't completely set it up the way I like, but this works better for now.

In `./.vscode/launch.json`, add the `logging` options to your config:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Your config name",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "logging": {
                "engineLogging": false,
                "moduleLoad": false,
                "exceptions": false,
                "browserStdOut": false
            },
// ... the rest of your existing config. surrounding code shown for placement purposes.
```

You may still want exceptions output to the console, but so far I've found that even handled exceptions are being logged.  I want to ignore those, so I've set `exceptions` to `false` here.

#### **Updated 2023-08-14** - Visual Studio configuration

User `ditoslav` asked about how to configure these for Visual Studio. Well, today I'm using VS 2022 and looked into it. I'm assuming it's the same for VS 2019.

1. Use the app menu: `Debug` -> `Options` (at the bottom of my list). This takes you to the debug section of the regular settings window.
2. Under the `Debugging` section, click `Output Window`
3. Step 2 updates the right half of the window (assuming all regions are set up the same). Set these to `Off` as you see fit-- this fixed it for me.

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

ALT: I turned the following options to off under `General Output Settings`:

- Module Load Messages
- Module Symbol Search Messages
- Module Unload Messages
- Step Filtering Messages
- Thread Exit Messages (This could be useful, though)

Comment: thank you -- didn't know where to set these up. That said, from https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md I noted another setting programOutput which may be of use as well, beyond the four listed here.

Comment: @Wellspring Yes, but I needed `programOutput`. If you log to the console, or you allow dotnet to log to the console, the debug console no longer shows the logs if that property is disabled.  At least, with an internal terminal.  If you launch the app with an external terminal, you can probably get logs in that one and use the debug console for debugging only.

Comment: understood -- and I left it enabled as well! I just noted it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @ps2goat what about VS2019? I just cannot find the config file or whatever to prevent logging

Comment: @ditoslav -- it's been a while, but I started using VS a bit today, and found the answer to your question. I updated my answer; I hope it helps. Instead of saving it in a project file, it looks like it's more of a local config.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio Code:

Use [omnisharp-vscode for .net core development](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode)
which gives you the possibilty to customize
[debugger launch with a json file](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md). 
For example, you could use the following options:

```
    "justMyCode":false*
    "symbolOptions": {
    "searchPaths": [
        "~/src/MyOtherProject/bin/debug",
        "https://my-companies-symbols-server"
    ],
    "searchMicrosoftSymbolServer": true,
    "cachePath": "/symcache",
    "moduleFilter": {
        "mode": "loadAllButExcluded",
        "excludedModules": [ "DoNotLookForThisOne*.dll" ]
       }
    }
```

For Visual Studio:

You could get rid of it, when you load the symbol files (pdb). When debugging, 
you could open the Module window (Debug -> Windows -> Module) and right click the module whose symbols is not loaded and then select Load Symbols...

If you want to disable "just my code", please open Tools -> options -> Debugging -> General and clear the checkbox "Enable Just my code (Managed only)"

Comment: Is it for Mac? I am using mac and I do not see any Tools menu :((

Comment: I am sorry. I thougt you were using visual studio. I updated my answer for visual studio code.

Comment: Thank you that worked for `Just My code` error. I am also getting a lot of messages for `Cannot find or open the PDB file.` Do you know which options to turn on/off to not see these messages?

Comment: -1 Don't follow this answer unless you want to debug system, framework, and other non-user code. Suggesting to disable optimization feature to get rid of simple log messages is unprofessional.